# Crystal Report with command doesn't appear all fields

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am trying to display data from 3 MySQL tables into one crystal report. I wrote my own query using the "Add Command" option in a "standard report creation wizard" window instead of using a connector to the database (because I want to write my own query's code)

the code below of query that I want to execute and I wrote in command:

```
SELECT
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum,
    ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork,
    ubc.boq_table.unit,
    ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity,
    ubc.boq_table.priceNum,
    ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary,
    ubc.summary.priceLastWorks,
    ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum,
    ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks
FROM
    ubc.boq_table
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.summary ON
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum = ubc.summary.itemNum
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.submittal ON
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum = ubc.submittal.itemNum
WHERE
    ubc.boq_table.projectName = 'proj'
UNION
SELECT
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum,
    ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork, 
    ubc.boq_table.unit, 
    ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity, 
    ubc.boq_table.priceNum, 
    ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary, 
    ubc.summary.priceLastWorks, 
    ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum, 
    ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks 
FROM
    ubc.summary
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.boq_table ON 
    ubc.summary.itemNum = ubc.boq_table.itemNum 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.submittal ON 
    ubc.summary.itemNum = ubc.submittal.itemNum 
WHERE 
    ubc.summary.projectName = 'proj'  
UNION
SELECT
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum,
    ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork,
    ubc.boq_table.unit,
    ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity,
    ubc.boq_table.priceNum,
    ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary, 
    ubc.summary.priceLastWorks, 
    ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum, 
    ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks 
FROM
    ubc.submittal 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.boq_table ON 
    ubc.submittal.itemNum = ubc.boq_table.itemNum 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ubc.summary ON 
    ubc.submittal.itemNum = ubc.summary.itemNum 
WHERE 
    ubc.submittal.projectName = 'proj' 
ORDER BY 
    itemNum;
```

the following code I wrote it in onLoad function of the form to display crystal report note that "FullOuterQuery" is the same of first code

```
 MySqlCommand Command = new MySqlCommand(FullOuterQuery, connection);
                adapter.SelectCommand = Command;
                adapter.Fill(table);
                ReportDocument doc;
                CrystalReport1 report = new CrystalReport1();
                report.SetDataSource(table);
                doc = new ReportDocument();
                doc.Load("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\WindowsFormsApp6\\WindowsFormsApp6\\WindowsFormsApp6\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
```

my problem is the crystal report has null values (actually not found values) because I retrieve from 3 tables and this error appears "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" I want to replace all null values with zero but I can't make this in a query that I wrote in command.

I tried to use a formula to check if the value is null then replace with zero
for example:

```
if(isnull({Command.priceCurrentWorks})) then 
       {Command.priceCurrentWorks} = 0
else 
   {Command.priceCurrentWorks} = {Command.priceCurrentWorks}
```

and I use a similar formula for each value may have null
and change option "Exception For Nulls" to "Default Value For Nulls" in formula's code editor
but still, the error occurs.

second problem that I wrote in a where condition projectName = 'proj' but the user should enter a project name like `where projectName = '"+ projectNameTextBox.tex+"' ;` how can I make this in a query that I wrote in command because when I am trying to edit that in FullOuterQuery (a query that is written in c# form) nothing change note: I tested my query in localhost phpMyAdmin and it worked.

**Update**
I remove formula and edit the SELECT query in command to be like this

```
SELECT
    ubc.boq_table.itemNum,
    ubc.boq_table.descriptionOfWork,
    ubc.boq_table.unit,
    ubc.boq_table.contractualQuantity,
    ubc.boq_table.priceNum,
    IFNULL(ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary,0),
    IFNULL(ubc.summary.priceLastWorks,0),
    IFNULL(ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum,0),
    IFNULL(ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks,0)
```

And when I am using the following code no error occurred but also no data occurred

```
 adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(FullOuterQuery, connection);

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds);
                ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
                cryRpt.Load("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\WindowsFormsApp6\\WindowsFormsApp6\\WindowsFormsApp6\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
                cryRpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear();
                cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
                crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

**UPDATE 2:**
when I name my tables in an adapter like `adapter.Fill(ds,"boq_table");`
and in dataSource for the report, it displays some data and some missing,
I create a data grid view with the same query of the report to see if there is any problem in data, data grid view display result as expected but I don't know why it doesn't in the report.
I verify database and each field and rebuild, also I create new crystal report but nothing differs

the following code is the last one (which appears some data)

```
 adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(FullOuterQuery, connection);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(ds,"boq_table");
                adapter.Fill(ds, "summary");
                adapter.Fill(ds, "submittal");

                ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["boq_table"];
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["summary"];
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["submittal"];

                cryRpt.Load("C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\WindowsFormsApp6\\WindowsFormsApp6\\WindowsFormsApp6\\CrystalReport1.rpt");
                cryRpt.DataSourceConnections.Clear();

                cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["boq_table"]);
                cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["summary"]);
                cryRpt.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["submittal"]);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;
                crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

the following fields don't appear

```
 IFNULL(ubc.summary.priceLastWorks,0),
    IFNULL(ubc.summary.executedQuantBetw2Sum,0),
    IFNULL(ubc.submittal.priceCurrentWorks,0)
```

you may think that there is a problem with IFNULL or because there is a field from another table but the following line of query display data correctly

```
IFNULL(ubc.summary.executedQuantLastSummary,0),
```

Comment: how did you crate your CrystalReport1.rpt, did you referenced your table correctly. i personally create a xml file from my dataset and use the xml file as datasource for my report. and i have a feeling your order of command sis somewhat off see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8010215/5193536

Comment: are you using a local database file inside your application? I am using MySQL phpMyAdmin localhost, I don't know if this can work with a dataset, I update the post depending on the link you attached please check my post again.

Answer (score 0):

make a stop point at

```
ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
```

and see, if the dataset ds has data at all.(or else you have to work on that

The next step is create a rpt file that uses that Data structure.

there is this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/8420629/5193536

Where you create an xsd source or like i do it use ds.writexml(filepath) and create a xml file and use this as Basic datasource to create your rpt file(It is like dtp).
I coulod only find a manual for that in german, but you find al ot of answer to specific questions.

So now you have a rpt file that can use the dataset ds, and doesn't mind the data

When you have created your rpt use your code to bring it into live by showing in the crystalviewer.

After the first time you make this, and understand the necessitys of crystal, it gets easier and you will spend some learning time to get a good report.

Comment: I gave you an answer, that helped with your problem. So accept it and give it an upvote.. As for your sql Problem, without any data and what you want, i really can't help you. If you had a bug, that i can find. But you have to experiment until you get your result. But i need a https://dbfiddle.uk example that shows the data, you got and the expected result